# CPU Identification on Virtual Machine

Tags: c#, wmi, virtual-machine

I use following c# code to get processor information. The Management class is null if I run my application on a virtual machine. I use Oracle VM VirtualBox as my virtual pc (Windows XP SP3)

```
System.Management.ManagementClass Management = new System.Management.ManagementClass("Win32_Processor");
```

Does anyone has experience about using such code and has problems in virtual machines.

Comment: That's not possible, the *new* operator never returns null.  Your problem must be virtual as well.

Comment: Yes Hans, you're right. ManagementClass instance is not null. Management["ProcessorId"] is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle VirtualBox does not provide such information.

Here is the related ticket.

https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/9046

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `GetInstances`?

```
System.Management.ManagementClass ManagementClass1 = new System.Management.ManagementClass("Win32_Processor");

System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection ManagementObjectCollection1 = ManagementClass1.GetInstances();

foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject managementobject in ManagementObjectCollection1) {
    Console.Out.WriteLine(managementobject.Properties["Name"].Value);
}

Console.In.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Yes @VSU, I'm using GetInstances() method. Seems that VirtualBox does not support all WMI processes.

Comment: Download BgInfo from Microsoft.com and see if it can obtain the correct CPU info. If it cannot, then VirtualBox is hiding it and there is no mistake in your code.

Comment: Also ensure that you have latest version of VBox and have Guest Additions installed. I have seen that VBox does hide some details. This is not unusual and is probably by design.